# Is there any good way to check the pdf file is same as word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

There is a problem that I use vba to print word document to pdf file but the pdf files sometimes are not same as word.

Example.

> 1.The pdf file page is not same as word document page.
>
> > The Word Document is 10 pages.
> >
> > The PDF file is 9 pages.
>
> 2.Word Document will just print the half to pdf.
>
> > The last page of word document maybe is 200 words but the pdf file only have 120 words.

I have a way to check this problem.

1.Check the page.

2.Check the last ten word is the same or not.

But there is a problem that the special symbol like "≦" can't be read by vba and can't be read by Acrobat API.

Any idea can handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "≦" use "<=".
If you have *Acrobat.tlb* reference than the number of pages is something like

```
Dim oPapp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim oPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim docPages as Long
Set oPapp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set oPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
oPDDoc.Open ("C:\test.pdf")
docPages = oPDDoc.numPages
```

Comment: I can't edit the document that I received. So if the document's word is "≦" and the pdf file's word is "≦" then I have to detect it is same word.